# disable the submit button

Tags: javascript

I have a contact form on my website that emails me info from interested parties. I don't want to use a captcha for various reasons. I just want to do something simple, like disable the submit button on the form until the user answers a simple question. Hopefully this will keep out some bots at least.
I found this on the web but it does absolutely nothing:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("Submit").disabled=true;
</script>
```

Can someone either correct this or give me something better?

Comment: Please at least provide your html

Comment: Try: `document.getElementById("Submit").setAttribute("disabled","true");`. It's about the same thing but it is worth the try! Also make sure that the ID is actually `Submit` and not `submit`

Comment: JavaScript will never help against bots. They will keep sending requests to your server.

Comment: @Shawn31313: No. Setting the property is fine and should be prefered.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's prefered. It was just a suggestion.

Comment: @OP: Do you have a button with the id `Submit`? When do you execute that line? Placing it inside `<script>` tags is probably not enough, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572. Do you get any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that if you are just testing that code that you have it in an onload function as such:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("Submit").disabled=true;
}
```

Also make sure that the ID is actually `Submit` and not `submit` because JavaScript is case-sensitive.

[JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/Qrpqp/) Example of disabling a button.

Comment: Ok I didn't use it as a function just put it inline after the form tag. I haven't written the test question code yet I wanted to see if the form button would get disabled. Someone asked about the html form code. here it is I apologise for the formatting I tried indenting to creat a code block but it doesn't work on your forum.

Comment: Did my solution fix it though?

Comment: No :( it doesn't on my computer. I don't really know how to use JSFIDDLE though. I did click run at the top and the "Doesn't Work" button got the focus.

Comment: Everybody I have had contact with on this forum has been real nice. I hate the structure of the forum itself though. No other forum I know of limits your input the way it does. Maybe I'll find y'all on again on a less constrictive forum! :)

Comment: @user1675122 This is a nice forum. You just have to get used to it. This is the number one forum for programmers I believe. Plus, you don't need to click on the run on JSFiddle. If you look in the `results` area. The first button is disabled because of the `JavaScript`.

Comment: Ok thanks! I don't have much room here for a comment, but I am using now a form and captcha hosted by a remote website. It functions well but would have been better if I could have programmed my own :(